# How to secure a Sails.JS API application against SQL and parameter injections?

Tags: api, sails.js, sql-injection

If I start a https://sailsjs.com/ App (Service with an API only, no frontend yet), how can I secure the API against SQL injection or unhandled parameters (e.g. type errors or wrong formats)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Policies

You can write policies to keep some users away from some controller actions. Check them [HERE](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies)

### 2. Write controllers that check for required parameters

It is that simple. Just return a `400` or `res.badRequest()` (check it out [HERE](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-bad-request) ) when a parameter is not in body.

### 3. Use Waterline to help you.

All methods from [HERE](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models) have ways to sanitize data. But it is your job to check for value types and other validation (like range). If you need to do a raw querie, then use it like [HERE](https://gist.github.com/Sailias/8404091) and also check for the [DOCS](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query) and the "valuesToEscape" arg.

### PS: 4. Use a validator service

Setup a service that requires a well known npm library to do checks for you! This is useful because you can make a common chunk of code available across your SailS app.

Comment: If you use Waterline, you don't have to escape parameters, right?

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask for the most. Good to know, that waterline already does prevent SQL injection. So the rest to secure the app is quite clear^^

Comment: Exactly, but only if you REALLY need to use raw queries. Usually find, findOne, update, associated with populate is enough for 95% of casesw, and they are secure by default. In a big project I only needed raw queries once...

Comment: @paulogdm: What npm would you recommend for these kinds of validation services?

Comment: @ShekharK.Sharma Validator (https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) should be enough. I use a lot of the "Sanitize" methods there.

Comment: Validator really is easy to use and integrate.